# Data structures VS Classes and what happens if they merge?

Tags: c#, design, data-structures, class-design

Alright so I've learned this:

**Classes** have public methods that perform operations on the class's data and they hide away their implementations.

**Data structures** on the other hand, completely expose their implementation through properties (getters and setters) and don't usually have methods.

So my question is, let's say that I have customer data structure that looks like this:

```
public class Customer
{
   public string FirstName { get ; set; }
   public string LastName { get ; set; }
   public List<Offer> Offers { get ; set; }
}
```

I would assume this to be a **data structure**.

but what if later during the project, I realize that I need to add some business logic to my customer data structure?

Like a method to add new offers because there's more logic in doing so than just adding it to the list?

It seems to me that this logic would belong inside of the data structure.

What happens then? Does the data structure turn in to a class? Or into some kind of third object type that I'm unaware of?

Is this **bad design**?

Comment: [data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) are not what you think these are. Consider [unlearning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unlearn) this and studying something that is less wrong instead - for example [OOSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Oriented_Software_Construction) chapters 6 and 7, having solid explanation of relation between ADTs and classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **not** bad design to add a method like that.  This sort of thing's actually very normal when classes are in their infancy.

But classes and data structures are a little bit different than you think, and one doesn't really oppose or exclude the other at all.  Most classes are data structures, and many data structures are classes.  Classes have a lot more to do with the syntax of a language - they're programmed into a language directly - whereas datastructures have more to do with how you personally intend to use certain things.  You tell a program what is and is not a class, but you do not generally tell a program what is and is not a data structure - you keep up with the latter yourself.

A class might involve methods - or it might not.  It also might involve data - or it might not.  Usually they'll involve both (especially in Java-style languages, where both are required), but this is not always true.  You could even have a class with neither methods nor data.

Without getting into any of the details of OOP, a class is mostly just a collection of methods and/or data.  And a class doesn't have to have public members, by the way.  I've used some whose members were all either internal or private, for instance.

A data structure is a little different.  It's basically a grouping of data that has been structured in some particular way for some particular purpose.  This may be a class.  Any time you see a class with more than one piece of data, that is generally a data structure.

Like a class, a data structure may either contain or forgo methods.  Unlike a class, however, it must contain some form of data (even if the data's just a couple of "blank" variables).

You can have data structures that are not classes.  For instance, imagine if you have two arrays: One is a list of people's first names, and one is a list of people's last names.  And if the nth element of the first array is somebody's first name, then the nth element of the second array is that same person's last name.  Even though the program and the programming language may have no idea these two arrays are connected, you do personally, just because you're keeping up with it.  Even though this is not a good example of how you would usually want to set things up, this still constitutes a data structure.

I know that might have been a little long, but hopefully it'll help.

Comment: To give an example, a Tree *data structure* can be implemented using *classes* in Java, but in C, it would probably be implemented with arrays or maybe structs.

Comment: This does help me understand, but shouldn't classes encapsulate as much of their implementation as possible? 

Wouldn't have having a great many getters or setters on a class "bad" ?

Comment: They do need to encapsulate as much as reasonably possible.  Especially in bigger classes, where most of your variables in a class are going to be specific to how that class works, not something that pertains to other classes.  So just declare variables like that private and don't provide any getters or setters.  This is still generally a data structure though, even if every variable is private and unexposed, as the class itself would still have access to all that data.

Comment: @Panzercrisis - So let's say in my example for the customer class above, what if I had about 10-15 properties on the object, plus all of the methods relating to the business logic of the customer.

Is there ever a point where some of the public properties should maybe be split and put in a different class? Isn't a class having a crapton of properties AND methods for business logic doing too much?

Comment: There's kind of a happy size for a class.  Other than that, it's usually either too small or too large.  Usually if it's too large, it does need to be broken into smaller classes, like you say.  In the original example, there are two related variables: `FirstName` and `LastName`.  There's an unrelated varialbe called `Offers`.  So far if you try to break up this class into a couple of subclasses, it's overkill.  But now if you add 15 more properties on top of it, it may or may not be overkill.  If some of those properties are called `Age`, `MiddleName`, `Birthdate`, etc., you start to see a...

Comment: ...common theme.  `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`, `MiddleName`, and `Birthdate` are all part of somebody's personal information.  So you would at least consider splitting all of those off into their own class, say `Person`, but depending on what else the `Customer` class has in it, it may or may not be a good idea.  So now `Customer` might contain a `Person` variable called `person`, as well as `Offers`, `tab`, `isBanned`, etc...

Comment: ...But many well-formed classes contain 10-15 variables, if not properties; something like 25 exposed properties or 50 variables is a much clearer sign something's gone wrong.

Comment: @Panzercrisis And in your experience, it would be fine for that class to have 13 properties, where about 9 of those are completely public? 

Isn't that breaking a lot of encapsulation and wouldn't that class have pretty low cohesion from having so many properties that aren't actually used in class's method?

Comment: The site's starting to tell me to avoid discussions in the comments...  Usually it's bad if you have 13 properties, 9 of which are public.  Usually it would cause encapsulation issues and such.  In the earlier comment though, I was partially taking Java-style languages into consideration, where any class is liable to automatically inherit 10 or 15 properties.  But part of the problem is that it's hard to give a good estimate of what a class should have in its own design, because this depends on the context.  Just use as few as reasonably possible, and break up classes when reasonably possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13684/discussion-between-darkalfx-and-panzercrisis)

Answer (score 1):

> I would assume this to be a data structure.

Specifically, it's a [record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_%28computer_science%29).

> Like a method to add new offers because there's more logic in doing so than just adding it to the list?

Is there some important condition you need to maintain in your `Offers` list? e.g. It needs to stay sorted? If so, then giving the whole program free access to the list is bad. Either you turn `Customer` into an abstraction (a class or interface), or you turn `Offers` into one, but you have to control access to that list somehow. Which one should become the abstraction depends on the rest of the program and what you're trying to do.

If there's no such condition, you can simply add plan ol' functions that take the `Customer` record as its argument and do whatever things you need to do to it.

The bottom line is that not every user-defined type in your program is going to be an abstraction of something. Sometimes you do have plain old data objects. You do need *some* abstractions, and your data structures will often be used as the private members of some class, but they could also appear as arguments or return values of a class's methods, especially simple types like tuples or records.